# Get sequence of random n numbers that add up to something but only from a specific set of numbers

Tags: c#, algorithm

What I need is:
e.g:

Sum should be equal to:
120 (user input)

Number of numbers/items:
80 (user input)

Range of numbers to be used in set(from):
0 (user input)

Range of numbers to be used in set(to):
4 (user input)

Output:
1,1,3,2,1,1,0,0,1,1,2,1,0,2,3,3,1,2,0,0,0,1,3,2,3,1,0,0,2,3,2,3,2,2,1,1,0,0,2,0,1,0,1,1,3,3,1,3,1,0,0,3,2,1,0,0,2,1,2,3,0,3,1,1,3,3,2,2,1,1,3,1,3,3,3,3,3,1,2,0

These are all numbers that are between 0 and 4, their sum is 120 and are 80 in total.

What i've done is:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool loopOn = true;
            Program p = new Program();
            Console.WriteLine("____________________________________________________________________________");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("Sum should be equal to:");
            int sum = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Number of items:");
            int items = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Range(from):");
            int from = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Range(to):");
            int to = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            while (loopOn == true)
            {
                List<int> number_list = p.createNumberSet(items, from, to);
                if (number_list.Sum() == sum)
                {
                    loopOn = false;
                    Console.WriteLine("____________________________________________________________________________");
                    Console.WriteLine("Start");
                    number_list.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
                    Console.WriteLine("Stop");
                    Console.WriteLine("____________________________________________________________________________");

                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit....");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }

        public List<int> createNumberSet(int itemNumber, int range_from, int range_to)
        {
            List<int> number_set = new List<int>();
            Random r = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; itemNumber > i; i++)
            {
                number_set.Add(r.Next(range_from, range_to));
            }
            return number_set;
        }
```

But this seems extremely in-efficent and doesn't seem to work with a lot of other examples. Does anyone have a better way of doing this?

Comment: what examples does it not work with ?

Comment: @Jawad e.g sum: 480, items: 80, range: 5 - 12;
or
sum: 10000, items: 1000, range: 0-1000

Comment: @react.noobie You cannot sum 1,000 values between 0-4 to 10,000.  Maybe you need to do a quick check to make sure the max number times the desired quantity of numbers is greater than the desired sum?  Also you'd need a similar check on the lower end.  Though it gets tricky if you allow for negative numbers.

Comment: @juharr you're probably right but isn't there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I am a bit lazy right now, so this is just an idea
Keep the first part:

```
bool loopOn = true;
Program p = new Program();
Console.WriteLine("____________________________________________________________________________");
Console.WriteLine("");
Console.WriteLine("Sum should be equal to:");
int sum = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Number of items:");
int items = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Range(from):");
int from = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Range(to):");
int to = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Now, first of all, check is a solution exists:

```
if (from * items > sum) {
    // There is no solution, handle accordingly
}
```

Let's focus on the interesting part now:
First create the list of necessary items

```
int[] number_set = new int[items];
for(int i = 0; i < items; i++) {
    number_set[i] = from;
}
```

Find the difference between the wanted sum and the current sum of the list

```
int left_to_add = sum - from * items;
int idx = 0;
Random r = new Random();
while(left_to_add > 0) {
    int toAdd = 0;
    if (left_to_add < range_to - range_from) {
        toAdd = r.Next(1, left_to_add);
    } else {
        toAdd = r.Next(1, range_to - range_from);
    }
    left_to_add -= toAdd;
    number_set[idx] += toAdd;
    idx++;
}
```

What's left to do is, convert the array to a list and shuffle it.
(I forgot that you actually can access list items by index, so there is no need to use an array as I did here)

Comment: What if `Next()` rolls tons of low numbers? Then you number_set would get much longer than desired.

Comment: The way I understood the question was, that the resulting list has to be at exactly 'items' long. Therefor number_set always has the exact same length. And even in my code the length of the list/array does not change after initialization

Answer (score 0):

At the algorithm level, this is what I would try:

Determine the number of each element, n[0], n[1], n[2], n[3] in your example (i.e. number of 0, number of 1 ...) and then generate a simple sequence by concatenating n[0] "0", n[1] "1", n[2] "2" and n[3] "3". Finally, a random sequence is obtained by performing a random permutation on this simple sequence.

The problem is therefore to determine the n[i].

1. The first step is to determine the average values of these n[i]. It your example, it is simple, as we can take average n_av[i]=20 for all index i.

In a more general case, we have to insure that

```
sum_i n_av[i]*i = sum_target (120 here) (1)
```

knowing that

```
sum_i (n[i]) = n = 80 here. (2)
```

In the general case, there is no necessary one unique good solution. I will try to propose an example of solution here if you provide an example of a difficult scenario.

2. The second step consists in selecting some random n[i] values around these average values. One possibility is to generate rounded Gaussian variables: we already know the averages, we just need to determine the variances. One possibility is to consider the variance that we will get if we were generating directly the random values, i.e. by considering the variance of the corresponding binomial variable :

   `var = n p(1-p)`. Here `p[i] = n_av[i]/n`
3. The last step consists in adjusting the values of the n[i] such that the sum of the n[i] is equal to the target. This is simply obtained by slightly increasing or decreasing some n[i] values.